# How to resolve 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table for storing tags called `Tags`. Now that table contains a foreign key column for the post that the tag belongs to called `PostId`.

In my controllers before posting a new tag, I check if the `Posts` table contains at least one record and if it does not then the default post id is 1 else the default post id is the id of the last post plus 1. However, am getting an Sqlite exception

> A foreign key constraint failed.

Code for the tag class

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; } 
    // default foreign key for the post id
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public Tag(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The post class

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other post definitions
}
```

I get the error on this line inside the `QueryController` file when I
try to save changes to database

```
public IActionResult HandleNewPost(string Title, string Body, string Tags){
   var tags = Tags.Split(" ");
   foreach(var str in tags){
     var tag = new Tag(str);
      //check if there is at least one post record
 
      if(_dbctx.Posts.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).LastOrDefault()==null){
       //the default post id is 1
       tag.PostId =1;
     }else{
       //the default post id is the id of the last post plus 1
        tag.PostId = _dbctx.Posts.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).LastOrDefault().Id+1;
    }
    //add the tag to the Tags table
    _dbctx.Tags.Add(tag);
   }
}
//saving changes throws the error
```

Code inside the migrations builder

```
/// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "posts",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Body = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    AuthoredOn = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    PostedBy = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Updated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    UpVotes = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                    DownVotes = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_posts", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "users",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Password = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Phone = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    LoginTimes = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: true),
                    LastLoginTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Avatar = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    Bio = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    BioUpdated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    DateCreated = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_users", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Answer",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Content = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    PostId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Answer", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Answer_posts_PostId",
                        column: x => x.PostId,
                        principalTable: "posts",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Comments",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    PostId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    CommentData = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    CommentOwner = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Comments", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Comments_posts_PostId",
                        column: x => x.PostId,
                        principalTable: "posts",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Tags",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    PostId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tags", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Tags_posts_PostId",
                        column: x => x.PostId,
                        principalTable: "posts",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Answer_PostId",
                table: "Answer",
                column: "PostId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Comments_PostId",
                table: "Comments",
                column: "PostId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Tags_PostId",
                table: "Tags",
                column: "PostId");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Answer");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Comments");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Tags");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "users");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "posts");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Highly suspect that this *the default post id is the id of the last post plus 1* logic is the reason why you face the foreign key constraint issue. You need to make sure that id for last post id +1 is really existed in your Post table.

Comment: Sound weird on your current logic. *HandleNewPost*, should create a new post record first and create the tag associate with the post. It seems you are reversing the flow.

Comment: @marc_s, yes but the entityframework is used inside the asp net core project. Perhaps I  should add the entityframework tag.

Comment: @YongShun you may be right. This code to post a new tag to database runs before another block of code below it that posts a new post to the posts table. It could be a foreign key integrity check failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I would say that you will have a high chance of getting the "Violate Foreign key constraint" issue as you are associating the tag with the post in which the `PostId` (last post id + 1) doesn't exist in the `Post` table.

You need to make sure that the associated `PostId` is existed/the `Post` entity is created before inserting the `Tag` entity.

```cs
public IActionResult HandleNewPost(string Title, string Body, string Tags)
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Title = Title,
        Body = Body
        // Other properties to assign if any
    };

    _dbctx.Posts.Add(post);
    _dbctx.SaveChanges();

    var tags = Tags.Split(" ");
    foreach(var str in tags)
    {
        var tag = new Tag(str);
        //check if there is at least one post record
 
        tag.PostId = post.Id;
        //add the tag to the Tags table
        _dbctx.Tags.Add(tag);
    }

    _dbctx.SaveChanges();

    // Your following logic implementation
}
```

If your `Post` entity is as below:

```cs
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

You can insert the `Post` with `Tags` entities through the `Tags` navigation properties. Reference: [Adding a graph of new entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-graph-of-new-entities)

```cs
public IActionResult HandleNewPost(string Title, string Body, string Tags)
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Title = Title,
        Body = Body,
        Tags = Tags.Split(" ").Select(x => new Tag(x)).ToList()
        // Other properties to assign if any
    };

    _dbctx.Posts.Add(post);
    _dbctx.SaveChanges();

    // Your following logic implementation
}
```

Comment: Tag posting should come after post insertion in simple terms?